# Percentage of closed questions

Tags: support, graphs

Is there a statistic somewhere that shows percentage of closed questions on basis of new questions ? Would be nice in a graphic form, but that isn't that important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go. Time is the horizontal axis.

[image]

Bonus graph of community wiki per day:

[image]

Comment: What tiem frame does this cover ?

Comment: From "day 0" somewhere around June 2008 to 30 Nov 2009 (the date of the latest data dump). I'll add these graphs to http://hewgill.com/~greg/stackoverflow/stats.html and keep it updated with future data dumps.

Comment: Also, what site is this ? Meta or SO ?

Comment: Sorry, didn't see that last comment. Excellent, thanks (btw, nice page).

Answer (score 2):

You can look for *all* closed questions by typing `closed:1` into the search box on the top right. At the moment of typing this, I get 10,347 results for closed questions on SO (which is corroborated by the list of closed questions you get to look at once you've broken 10,000 Rep).

The ratio of closed questions to new questions (with "new" being roughly the last 24 hours) can be found by sorting the list of [closed questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=closed%3a1&tab=newest) and [all questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=newest) by "newest" and simply counting. Here are some numbers:

- 53 questions closed in the last 24 hours
- 1617 questions asked in the last 24 hours
- 3.28% of questions asked in the last 24 hours are closed
- 2.4% of *all* questions on SO are closed

Comment: I'm more interested in a ratio (closed/new) on a time basis ...

Comment: That would depend very much on what you considered "new".

Comment: Well, for example, questions asked on that day vs. closed questions of those asked on that day - percentage on a day basis for last 365 days.

Comment: How do you get the exact number of results? I'm not seeing the number anywhere in the results screen.  Or are you mentally doing the math of `(answers-per-page * (pages-1)) + answers-on-last-page`?

Comment: It was just mental math.